# ActiveMQ Artemis: can't create broker: function not implemented

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, activemq-artemis

I used to create brokers in ActiveMQ Artemis on both Windows, Linux and in WSL. There was never a problem.
Except on one of my machine having Windows and running WSL2.

I did everything the same when installing artemis:

```
sudo groupadd artemis
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g artemis -d /opt/artemis artemis
cd /opt
sudo wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/activemq-artemis/2.12.0/apache-artemis-2.12.0-bin.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvzf apache-artemis-2.12.0-bin.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-artemis-2.12.0 artemis
sudo chown -R artemis: artemis
sudo chmod o+x /opt/artemis/bin/
sudo rm apache-artemis-2.12.0-bin.tar.gz
```

It installs, but when I try to create my own broker instance:

```
/opt/artemis/bin/artemis create --user app --password pwd --allow-anonymous test
```

I've got the following error message:

```
Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented
```

I've tried it several times, even uninstalled ActiveMQ Artemis and removed the user and group and started the whole process again, but the result was always the same.

I can't figure out what the difference would be or how to fix the problem. Any help would be highly appreciated!

UPDATE 1:
There is not much log, but turning on verbose mode gives the following lines:

```
Executing org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Create create --verbose --user app --password pwd --allow-anonymous test
Home::/opt/artemis, Instance::null
Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented
```

Comment: Can you share the log before the initialization error?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino: there is not much log, but I updated the question what I was able to get by using `--verbose` option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell the message "Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented" comes from the [AIO integration layer](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis-native/blob/master/src/main/c/org_apache_activemq_artemis_nativo_jlibaio_LibaioContext.c#L569). I recommend you try creating the instance using `--nio` to force the broker to use the Java-based NIO storage interface rather than the native AIO layer which appears to be malfunctioning in your environment.

Comment: That was the solution.