# Failed to deploy ActiveMQ Artemis in Docker container on Mac M1

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to run ActiveMQ Artemis on Mac M1.

```
docker run --detach --name mycontainer -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 --rm apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
```

```
2024-02-09 20:30:14 CREATE_ARGUMENTS=--user artemis --password artemis --silent --require-login --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia
 Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented

 Usage: artemis help [<args>...]
 use 'help <command>' for more information
     [<args>...]
```

If I will use

```
EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio --host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia"
```

> [Too many errors, abort]
> 2024-02-09 20:44:26 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped

I have used:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  activemq-artemis:
    container_name: artemis_simple
    image: apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
    environment:
      ARTEMIS_USER: "artemis"
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: "artemis"
      EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio"
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
   restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - artemis

networks:
  artemis:
    driver: bridge
```

It started at first, there were a few errors, but however I can't connect to the web console

```
Auto tuning journal ...
2024-02-09 20:34:50 done! Your system can make 8.62 writes per millisecond, your journal-buffer-timeout will be 115999
2024-02-09 20:34:50 
2024-02-09 20:34:50 You can now start the broker by executing:  
2024-02-09 20:34:50 
2024-02-09 20:34:50    "/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin/artemis" run
2024-02-09 20:34:50 
2024-02-09 20:34:50 Or you can run the broker in the background using:
2024-02-09 20:34:50 
2024-02-09 20:34:50    "/var/lib/artemis-instance/bin/artemis-service" start
............

[Too many errors, abort]
2024-02-09 20:44:26 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

Who has any idea how you can deploy ActiveMQ Artemis on a Mac M1 in Docker container?

Comment: The container should print its configuration in to the console. Can oyu share the log of the container? Also, as far as I know, the environment variables are prefixed with `ARTEMIS`, not `AMQ`.

Comment: I have corrected and indicated above

Comment: the log is large. I can only transfer it as a file. but you won't be able to attach it here

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873542/artemis-cant-create-broker-function-not-implemented) recommends using `--nio`, but this is not present in the command line despite `EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio"`. Please make sure you use the correct configuration. I also recommend setting `--http-host 0.0.0.0` if `--nio` is used: `EXTRA_ARGS: "--http-host 0.0.0.0 --nio`.

Comment: EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio --host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia" - This causes an error. indicated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented` is caused by the fact that AIO isn't working in your environment as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873542/artemis-cant-create-broker-function-not-implemented). Therefore, you need to use NIO instead of AIO.

However, if you **only** specify "--nio" in your `EXTRA_ARGS` that will overwrite the default `EXTRA_ARGS` (i.e. `--http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia`) and prevent you from accessing the web console.

I believe the `[Too many errors, abort]` error is due to a platform mismatch. You need to ensure you're using the `arm64` image variant.

Putting it all together now...

This should work to use NIO, bind the embedded web server to `0.0.0.0` so you can access the web console from outside the container, and ensure you're using the right platform:

```
docker run --platform linux/arm64 -e ARTEMIS_USER=artemis -e ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=artemis -e EXTRA_ARGS="--nio --host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia" --name mycontainer -it -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine
```

This should also work with `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: "3.8" 
services: 
  activemq-artemis: 
    container_name: artemis_simple 
    image: apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine 
    environment: 
      ARTEMIS_USER: "artemis" 
      ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: "artemis" 
      EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio --host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia" 
    ports: 
      - "8161:8161" 
      - "61616:61616" 
    networks: 
      - artemis
    platform:
      "linux/arm64"

networks: 
  artemis: 
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I did this, however, I get an error: at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:64)
Couldn't perform sync calculation, using default values ... 

Could not start artemis-service

Comment: [Too many errors, abort]

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify somewhere that you want the `arm64` variant of `apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine`. Try adding `--platform linux/arm64` to your `docker run` command.

Comment: It's ok.  docker run --platform linux/arm64 -e ARTEMIS_USER=artemis -e ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=artemis -e EXTRA_ARGS="--nio --host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia" --name mycontainer -it -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine